# What does BBChan mean?

Tags: wesshar-wars

In the Wess'har Wars series by Karen Traviss the principal European news network is called BBChan. What is this an acronym for?

Comment: Good question. I've been through all six books looking for the words Broadcasting, British, Channel, bioscreen, Chan and BB and I'm none the wiser for it.

Comment: A portmanteau of BBC and 4chan?  I haven't read the books, but that's sure what it looks like (and the books postdate 4chan).

Comment: Is there a reason to think it's not "British Broadcasting Channel"?  An allusion to the real BBC (British Broadcasting Corporation.)  Sort of like writing a story about a news network in the USA named "Hound News" (instead of Fox News.)  I haven't read the books, so maybe there's a reason that's no good, but it seems the most obvious meaning to me.

Comment: @Steve-O - There's no *special* reason to assume that it's not, but on this site we prefer evidence-based answers.

Comment: [This lengthy Interview](http://strangehorizons.com/non-fiction/articles/interview-karen-traviss/) with the author, Karen Traviss, doesn't mention BBChan but she used to work for, and still respects, the BBC so it doesn't appear to be any kind of "slap" at them.